# Removing trailing comma from CSV data

Tags: c#, csv

This is the Code for adding comma after another number, but I want to delete the last comma:

```
str_MSISDN.Append("'" + _MSISDN[x].TrimStart() + "'" + ",");
```

Comment: Can you show us the entire loop, and which version of .NET are you using?

Comment: I am using the following approach on string... `myString= myString.Trim().TrimEnd(',');`

Answer (score 12):

Instead of manually appending things, I suggest you use `String.Join` which will get it right to start with. You can use LINQ to do the trimming of the values. For example:

```
string x = string.Join(",", _MSISDN.Select(x => "'" + x.TrimStart() + "'")
                                   .ToArray());
```

EDIT: A nicer version of this is available with [MoreLINQ](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) and its [`ToDelimitedString`](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/ToDelimitedString.cs) method:

```
string x = _MSISDN.Select(x => "'" + x.TrimStart() + "'")
                  .ToDelimitedString(",");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do that using the [`TrimEnd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend.aspx) method (when you are done appending):

```
str_MSISDN = str_MSISDN.ToString().TrimEnd(',');
```

Comment: I am using the following approach on string... `myString= myString.Trim().TrimEnd(',');`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the String.TrimEnd() method:

```
[your value] = str_MSISDN.ToString().TrimEnd(",".ToCharArray())
```

Comment: I am using the following approach on string... `myString= myString.Trim().TrimEnd(',');`

Comment: Yup, I use this more often now too:
[your value] = str_MSISDN.ToString().TrimEnd(',')

Answer (score 1):

My favourite way of doing this kind of thing is to use the string.Join method:

```
string str_MSISDN = string.Join(", ", _MSISDN);
```

(assuming that _MSISDN is an array of strings)

If you want to trim the start of each item you can do this:

```
string str_MSISDN = string.Join(", ", _MSISDN.Select(x=>x.TrimStart()).ToArray());
```

Note how you have to call .ToArray since the Join method wants an array not an IEnumerable

Answer (score 0):

I'd say don't add it in the first place, you've several options for doing this.

1) Use string.join

2) Restructure your loop as follows

```
int i = 0;
if (_MSISDN.Length > 0)
{
    str_MSISDN.Append("'" + _MSISDN[i++].TrimStart() + "'")
    while( i < _MSISDN.Length )
        str_MSISDN.Append(",'" + _MSISDN[i++].TrimStart() + "'");
}
```