# Remove last comma from json in c#?

Tags: c#

How could I last comma from my json: I am getting this as output json

```
{Floor_Id:"1094",Booth_Count:12},{Floor_Id:"1095",Booth_Count:10},
```

This is my C# Code:

```
StringBuilder json_result = new StringBuilder();
List<XElement> industries = ExpoHallXML.Descendants("industry").ToList();
                if (industries != null && industries.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (XElement industry in industries)
                    {
                        foreach (XElement floor in industry.Descendants("floor"))
                        {
                            if (floor.Attribute("id").Value != "0")
                            {
                                json_result.Append("{");
                                json_result.Append("Floor_Id:" + cmh.json_str(floor.Attribute("id").Value) + ",");
                                int booth_count = 0;
                                foreach (XElement page in floor.Descendants("page"))
                                {
                                    booth_count = page.Descendants("booth").Count();
                                    json_result.Append("Booth_Count:" + booth_count +"},");
                                }

                            }

                        }

                    }
                }
            return json_result.ToString();
```

Please help!
Thanks

Comment: is there a good reason you use a stringbuilder to manually create json strings? There are libraries like JSON.Net that can do that for you, with the added benefit that they will create valid JSON and have received extensive testing.

Comment: You mean this: json_result.LastIndexOf(",") ==  strgroupids.Length-1? json_result.Remove(strgroupids.Length - 1): json_result;

Comment: Just trim the last character from your manually-built string?  Why are you manually building JSON in the first place?

Comment: See [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741740/removing-trailing-comma-from-csv-data) (dealing with the same thing with CSV extraneous commas) where the highest voted answer is also "don't do that, do it properly instead".  I agree with the above comments about manually building it - use the right tool instead, rather than trying to fix the broken output.  Also note that your output is not technically valid json - all the keys should have quotes around them.

Answer (score 5):

I think this method is best option.

```
json_result.TrimEnd(',')
```

Comment: I would think that using a JSON serializer would be an even better option.

Answer (score 1):

Just a line before the return statement you can take the substring of the builder with length -1. Like below

```
        if(json_result.Length > 0)
        {
             json_result.Remove(json_result.Length - 1, 1);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if creating a JSON that way is not the preferred one, a suggestion I can give when you are concatenating string fragments by something is to use the [string.Join()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) method. This put the commas in the required places and made the code readable.